# Continuous data binning based on observation distribution/frequency to decide bin range r dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, quantile, binning, continuous

I have now for days without luck scanned the internet for help on this issue. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated! (especially in a tidyverse-friendly syntax)

I have a tibble with approx. 4300 rows/obs and 320 columns. One column is my dependent variable, a continuous numeric column called "RR" (Response Ratios). My goal is to bin the RR values into 10 factor levels. Later for Machine Learning classification.

I have experimented with the cut() function with this code:

```
df <- era.af.Al_noNaN %>%
  rationalize() %>%
  drop_na(RR) %>%
  mutate(RR_MyQuantile = cut(RR,
                              breaks = unique(quantile(RR, probs = seq.int(0,1, by = 1 / numbers_of_bins))), 
                              include.lowest = TRUE))
```

But I have no luck, because my bins come out with equal n in each, however, that does not reflect the distribution of the data.. I have studied a bit here https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-feature-engineering-part-1-continuous-numeric-data-da4e47099a7b but I simply cannot achieve the same in R.

[Here is the distribution of my RR data values grouped into classes *not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr2g2.png)

Comment: So what DO you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `hist()` to get the breaks. It's for plotting histograms but it also provides other associated data as side effect. In the example below, the plot is suppressed by `plot = FALSE` to expose the breaks data. Then, use that in `cut()`. This should give you the cutoffs, maintaining the distribution of the variable.

```
hist(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = 5, plot = FALSE)
# $breaks
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8
# 
# $counts
# [1] 32 57 49 12
# 
# ...<omitted>

breaks <- hist(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = 5, plot = FALSE)$breaks

dat <- iris %>% 
  mutate(sepal_length_group = cut(Sepal.Length, breaks = breaks))

dat %>% 
  count(sepal_length_group)

#   sepal_length_group  n
# 1              (4,5] 32
# 2              (5,6] 57
# 3              (6,7] 49
# 4              (7,8] 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

I also experimented using cut() and then count(). Then I use the labels=FALSE to give labels that can be used in a new mutate for a new column with character names of the intervals groups..

```
numbers_of_bins = 10

df <- era.af.Al_noNaN %>%
  rationalize() %>%
  drop_na(RR) %>%
  mutate(RR_MyQuantile = cut(RR,
                              breaks = unique(quantile(RR, probs = seq.int(0,1, by = 1 / numbers_of_bins))), 
                              include.lowest = TRUE))

head(df$RR_MyQuantile,10)

df %>% 
  group_by(RR_MyQuantile) %>% 
  count()
```